# TFS 15 RC2 - Build Agent Publish to Packages Feed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've been unsuccessful with having my build publish to the new Package Feed in TFS 15 RC2.  I'm currently running TFS offline and using a local build agent.  I've followed these [instructions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build) to no avail.

Since the last image in those instructions is cropped around the URL, and that URL was specific to VSTS online, I thought mine might be wrong.  So I tried the following (none worked):

1. Using http://[computername]:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/{feedName}/nuget/v3/index.json
   gives an error when it tries to prompt for input of credentials in
   interactive mode.
2. Using http://[computername]:8080 gives a 404.
3. Using http://[computername]:8080/tfs gives same error as #1.
4. Using http://[computername]:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection gives same error as #1

Since some errors happened while trying to do an interactive prompt, I thought it might be a permission error.  The following links give some information, but it seems like the Build Agent should already be in the right category for publishing permissions.

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/common-identities
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth

Anyone happen to know a solution?  Thanks!

### **EDIT**

The build agent was running as NT AUTHORITY/Network Service, which is the default of the agent config.  I removed this agent and configured it to run under my user account, which is an admin on the system.  After doing so, I was able to publish without issues to the Packages using the URL in #1 (as Cece below has written).  Is there something else I need to do to get the permissions set for the default agent?

Answer (score 0):

The **Internal Feed URL** is the NuGet Package Source URL for the feed you want to publish to.

When you create a new Feed, navigate to your feed, and select **Connect to feed**. You'll see the NuGet package source URL. The format should be like: `http://{tfsserver}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/{FeedName}/nuget/v3/index.json`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cece, that unfortunately still gives me same error as#1.  I've edited my links as I noticed I typed them in a bit wrong here.